# How to access vector inside a structure?

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I want to know how to access a vector inside a structure as defined below

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Hello{
    vector<int>vec ;
};

struct Hello *h[1][1];

int main()
{
    struct Hello *v = (struct Hello *)malloc(sizeof(struct Hello));
    h[0][0]=v;
    0][0]->vec.push_back(13);
    //How to add 13 to vector vec?
    //It shows an error. But why?
    cout<<h[0][0]->vec.at(0)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do not use `malloc` in c++, use `new`

Comment: Ideally don't use new either

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem:

```
struct Hello *v = (struct Hello *)malloc(sizeof(struct Hello));
```

(As an aside, `struct` is superfluous every time it was used in that line.)

It does allocate space for a `Hello`, but does not construct it.
And `Hello` has a non-trivial ctor because its member `std::vector` has one, thus omitting the call to the ctor is wrong.

Either use placement-new to in-place construct the `Hello`, or better yet allocate and construct in one go the C++ way:

```
Hello *v = new Hello;
// andd later deallocate
delete v;
```

Best, just avoid dynamic allocation altogether:

```
Hello h;
```

Member-access uses `.` or for pointers `->`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you write code in C++.

First, as properly mentioned in the comments, do not use `malloc` ever. Use `new` if you need dynamic memory allocation. Otherwise you would have non-constructed objects, like you have already been told.

Second, do not use `new` when you do not have to. If you need dynamic memory allocation, most probably you want to manage this memory with a *smart pointer*, like `std::unique_ptr`. To construct a `unique_ptr<T>`, use `std::make_unique<T>()` function. Using *`make_unique`* will make you program leak-free and exception safe at zero cost. Using `make_unique()` will prevent some tricky situations with leaking due to exceptions and save you a couple of keystrokes when writing the code. At zero cost, of course. See [GotW #89 Solution: Smart Pointers](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/).

Third, most likely you don't even need dynamic memory allocation here. This is not Java, we love to allocate things on the stack. Remember that `std::vector` itself does dynamic memory allocation to store its buffer. And due to *move semantics* it can move this storage effective at runtime. There is no much sense to allocate `vector` itself in dynamic memory. See [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Do a search on each *emphasized* item for details.